# Delay of less than one second, Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, grand-central-dispatch

I can't update Swift because the last time I tried to, it simply didn't work (see the tons of one star reviews on the app store), so other solutions I've found, for Swift 3.0, don't work for me.

The code I'm using to delay a function is:

```
   let time = dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW), 1 * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        //random function
    }
```

What I want is for the delay to be less than 1. Changing the "1" to "0.3" doesn't work because

> Binary operator * cannot be applied to operands of type **Int64** and **Double**.

Does anybody know any tricks to make the delay less than 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler is saying that you cannot use `*` with two different operands type `Int64` and `Double` as of `delta` argument of `dispatch_time` is type of `Int64` you can made it like this.

```
let time = dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW), Int64(Double(NSEC_PER_SEC) * 0.5))
dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    //random function
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great! I upvoted, but I don't have enough reputation for it to show.

Comment: @JohnKasich_2016 Welcome mate :)

Comment: Didn't know this. Thank you again!

Comment: @JohnKasich_2016 Welcome mate, Glad you know that now :)